# Code compiles without any error when missed return statement from catch block

Tags: objective-c, try-catch

Why does following code compile fine without any error?

```
- (NSArray *) getSomeObjects
{
    @try
    {
        NSArray * arrayToReturn = [NSArray array];

        // Perform some oprations on arrayToReturn

        return arrayToReturn;
    }
    @catch (NSException * exception)
    {
        // Uh Oh!!! I got an exception.
    }

    // See I am not returning anything from here
    // and code still compiles fine without any
    // compiler error.
}
```

On any exception I need to return an empty NSArray after my @catch is executed.

Is there any compiler flag in Xcode to warn these missing return statements as errors?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but exceptions in objective-c should only ever be used to crash the program in the case of critical programmer error. You should almost never be using try-catch anyway. The recommended way to do error handling in objective-c is to return error codes (or `BOOL`) to indicate success/failure,  or return an `NSError` object, or specify one as an output parameter.

Comment: Objective-C isn't Java.  The error checking for things such as this is not robust.  Remember, the compiler is under no obligation to issue warnings.

Comment: @OrionEdwards I agree that we should avoid using try-catch in Objective-C. The reason I was using try-catch is, I have an application on AppStore with millions users. In last application update we introduced some critical bug by changing the data-models. These data models were saved in NSUserDefaults using NSKeyedArchiver. Now in the application update when reading these from NSUserDefaults it crashed when trying to unarchive data using "NSKeyedUnarchiver". For quick fix (until we have proper fix in place) we have added try catch while unarchiving data and flush the old saved data if it fails.

Comment: You don't even need the first return. The compiler will ignore the return completely, even with a completely empty @try {} @catch() {}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as the compiler is concerned, the `return` statement in the `@try` block is always reached during normal execution. It doesn't think 'oh, there might be an exception on this line, therefore the `return` statement on the next line will never get reached'. Otherwise, there would need to be a warning for all methods with a return value :)

The try/catch block doesn't change this.

At least, this is how I understand it. I welcome anyone to correct me/expand on this/explain it better.

Edit to address this:

> On any exception I need to return an empty NSArray after my @catch is executed.

You can put another `return` statement in your `@catch` block, for if there is an exception.

Interestingly, you do not want to put another `return` in the `@finally` block for this purpose, as this will override/supersede/replace the `return` in the `@try` block, even if the one in the `@try` block is reached normally.